# UI router - Set up outside login page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to modify the [blur-admin](https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin/) project adding a login page with its own controller.

So I created a controller folder inside the pages folder called `demoadmin.login`.
The login is working well, but now, I want to show it outside the dashboard, I mean as standalone page.

Currently it is showing the following:

[image]

But I want to show it outside:

[image]

This is my `app.js` file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('bluradmin', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.sortable',
    'ui.router',
    'ngTouch',
    'toastr',
    'ui.slimscroll',
    'angular-progress-button-styles',
    'ngStorage',
    //'smart-table',
    //"xeditable",
    //'ngJsTree',

    'bluradmin.theme',
    'bluradmin.pages',
    'bluradmin.login'
]).run(function ($localStorage) {
    console.log($localStorage);
});
```

And my `pages.module.js` was modified:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('bluradmin.pages', [
        'ui.router',
        'bluradmin.pages.dashboard'
    ])
        .config(routeConfig);

    /** @ngInject */
    function routeConfig($urlRouterProvider, baSidebarServiceProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    }

})();
```

How can I set up the `ui-router` to obtain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your index.html:

```
<div ui-view>
</div>
```

At your app.html

```
 <div class="row main" ui-view>
 </div>
```

Then your config:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


    $stateProvider

        .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    })

    .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            templateUrl: 'templates/app.html'
        })

     .state('someOtherState', {
         parent: 'app',
         url: '/someUrl',
         templateUrl: 'templates/someTemplate.html'
     })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

Answer (score 1):

Define an abstract view/state for the App, and define another one separated view with the login. Something like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'menu.html'
    })

    .state('app.home', {
        url: 'home',        
        views: {
            'page-view': {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
            }
        }
    })

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        }
    })
```

Inside the menu.html yo should have something like this:

```
<div ui-view="page-view"></div>
```